# Why does my array object output only the last input?

Tags: java

I am currently in the process of practicing the utilization of array objects. In the provided program, I have restricted the creation of objects to only even numbers. Please refer to the given code and output below to understand the error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("the number of object you want to create for class X : ");
        int choose = sc.nextInt();

         X obj[] = new X[choose];

        if(choose>=2 && choose%2==0)
        {

            int input;
            for(int i=0;i<choose;i++)
            {
                System.out.print("insert the value for the "+ordinal(i+1)+" obj against odd: ");
                input=sc.nextInt();
                obj[i].odd=input;
            }
        }
        else return;

        for(int k=0;k<choose;k++)
        {
            System.out.println(obj[k].odd);
        }
    }
    public static String ordinal(int i) {
        int mod100 = i % 100;
        int mod10 = i % 10;
        if (mod10 == 1 && mod100 != 11) {
            return i + "st";
        } else if (mod10 == 2 && mod100 != 12) {
            return i + "nd";
        } else if (mod10 == 3 && mod100 != 13) {
            return i + "rd";
        } else {
            return i + "th";
        }
    }

}

class X
{
    static int odd;
}
```

the output is showing something like this below

```
the number of object you want to create for class X : 4
insert the value for the 1st obj against odd: 5
insert the value for the 2nd obj against odd: 4
insert the value for the 3rd obj against odd: 3
insert the value for the 4th obj against odd: 2
2
2
2
2
```

while I am expecting my output to be

```
the number of object you want to create for class X : 4
insert the value for the 1st obj against odd: 5
insert the value for the 2nd obj against odd: 4
insert the value for the 3rd obj against odd: 3
insert the value for the 4th obj against odd: 2
5
4
3
2
```

please advice me what change I need  to bring in my code thank you

Comment: Can you share the snippet where you process the input?

Comment: I have edited my question, please check it again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `X`'s data member is `static`, meaning it belongs to the class, not a specific instance, and you just keep overwriting it in each iteration of the loop. Instead, you should have it as an instance member (and probably have a constructor to initialize it:

```java
class X
{
    int odd;
    public X(int odd) {
        this.odd = odd;
    }
}
```

And then create a new instance in each iteration of the loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < choose; i++) {
    System.out.print("insert the value for the " + ordinal(i + 1) + " obj against odd: ");
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    obj[i] = new X(input);
}
```